# Python loop through list of csv and check for value?

Tags: python, loops

I have five .csv's that have the same fields in the same order that need to be processed as such:

- Get list of files
- Make each file into a dataframe
- Check if a column of letter-number combinations has a specific value (different for each file) eg: check if the number `PT333` is in `column1` for the file name `data1`:

```
column1   column2    column3    
PT389     LA       image.jpg
PT372     NY       image2.jpg
```

- If the column has a specific value, print which value it has and the filename/variable name that i've assigned to that file, and then rename that dataframe to `output1`

I tried to do this, but I don't know how to make it loop and do the same thing for each file.
At the moment it returns the number, but I also want it to return the data frame name, and I also want it to loop through all the files (a to e) to check for all the values in the `numbers` list.

This is what I have:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")
os.chdir(home + f'/files/')

data = glob.glob('data*.csv')
data

# If you have tips on how to loop through these rather than 
# have a line for each one, open to feedback
a = pd.read_csv(data[0], encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False)
b = pd.read_csv(data[1], encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False)
c = pd.read_csv(data[2], encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False)
d = pd.read_csv(data[3], encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False)
e = pd.read_csv(data[4], encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False)
filenames = [a,b,c,d,e]
filelist= ['a','b','c','d','e']

# I am aware that this part is repetitive. Unsure how to fix this,
# I keep getting errors
# Any help appreciated
numbers = ['PT333', 'PT121', 'PT111', 'PT211', 'PT222']
def type():
    for i in a.column1:
        if i == numbers[0]:
            print(numbers[0])
        elif i == numbers[1]:
            print(numbers[1])
        elif i == numbers[2]:
            print(numbers[2])
        elif i == numbers[3]:
            print(numbers[3])
        elif i == numbers[4]:
            print(numbers[4])
type()
```

Also happy to take any constructive criticism as to how to repeat less code and make things smoother. TIA

Comment: If all you need is just to check if that particular string exist in the file, it might be easier to just read the file content and return the file name if target is in content.  Also, in terms of critique - look into [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  There are lots of opportunities to put your code into loops or nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
for file in glob.glob('data*.csv'):       # loop through each file
    df = pd.read_csv(file,                # create the DataFrame of the file
             encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
             error_bad_lines=False)
    result = df.where( \                  # Check where the DF contains these numbers
                 df.isin(numbers)) \
                .melt()['value'] \        # melt the DF to be a series of 'value'
                .dropna() \               # Remove any nans (non match)
                .unique().tolist()        # Return the unique values as a list.
    if result:                            # If there are any results 
        print(file, ', '.join(result)     # print the file name, and the results
```

Remove the comments and trailing spaces if you are copying and pasting the code. for the `result` line, in case you run into `SyntaxError`.

As mentioned you should be able to do the same without DataFrame as well:

```
for file in glob.glob('data*.csv'):
    data = file.read()
    for num in numbers:
        if num in data:
            print(file, num)
```

Comment: Share the love, pay it forward :)

Answer (score 1):

> Also happy to take any constructive criticism as to how to repeat less
> code and make things smoother.

I hope you don't mind that i started with code restructure. it makes explaining the next steps easier

### loading the Files Array

Using list builder allows us to iterate through the files and load them into an a list in 1 line. It also has a lot of memory and time benefits.

```py
files = [pd.read_csv(entry, encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False) for entry in data]
```

[more on comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/)

### Type Function

First we need an argument so that we can give call this function for any given file.  Along with the list we can loop over it with a for each loop.

### Calling the Type Function on Multiple Files

We use for each loops again here

```py
for file in files:
    type(file)
```

[more on python for loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

```py
def type(file):
    for value in file.column1:
        if value in numbers:
            print(value)
```

## Result

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")
os.chdir(home + f'/files/')

#please note that i am use glob instead of glob.glob here.
data = glob('data*.csv')
files = [pd.read_csv(entry, encoding='ISO-8859-1', error_bad_lines=False) for entry in data]


numbers = ['PT333', 'PT121', 'PT111', 'PT211', 'PT222']

def type(file):
    for value in file.column1:
        if value in numbers:
            print(value)

for file in files:
    type(file)
```

Comment: This is super comprehensive and great- thanks. One thing - do you know how I can print the data frame name along with the value from the 'numbers' list it returns? @CWB

Comment: @HenriettaShalansky Glad to help. Before I change the code, I'd like know what your goal is. Are you trying to count how many times a value is in each csv's column1?

Comment: Your solution helped, i figured how to do it, and na -  I'm trying to check if any of the values in the 'numbers' is in column1, if it is - it means the dataframe is of a certain category, and I then need to process them each differently

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the type function, and calling it slightly differently

```
    def type(x):
        for i in x.column1:
            if i == numbers[0]:
                print(i, numbers[0])
            elif i == numbers[1]:
                print(i, numbers[1])
            elif i == numbers[2]:
                print(i, numbers[2])
            elif i == numbers[3]:
                print(i, numbers[3])
            elif i == numbers[4]:
                print(i, numbers[4])

    for j in filenames:
            type(j)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped how do also print the dataframe name that the 'number' belongs to?